# Variabel is not defined inside methods VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been defining an object inside VueJs method, and want to use that object for axios like this :

```
data() {
         return {
             name : '',
             password: '',
             email: ''
         }
     },

     methods: {
         submit() {
             sendData = {
                 name: this.name,
                 password: this.password,
                 email: this.email
             }

             axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/users', sendData)
             .then(response => {
                 console.log(response);
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.log(error)
             })
         }
     }
```

the output is `ReferenceError: sendData is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `sendData` is not declared anywhere. Just add `const` before `sendData` like so.

```
const sendData = {
  name: this.name,
  password: this.password,
  email: this.email
}
```

Comment: But `sendData` *is* defined. `sendData = { ... }`, and in the same scope as the axios call.

Comment: @DrewReese Try it in your browser console. It works just fine as a variable declaration. OP's error seems odd given this. https://jsfiddle.net/8doap61v/